# Android Webview: local html loads external css and .js files - Cannot Access Function In External .js

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I have a webview that loads a local html file located in my assets folder (i.e index.html). I load it with this call:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

It's structured like any normal html file with, title, head, and body tags. The head tag contain script and link tags that point to external (NOT in local Android build but on external servers) .js and css files. I know the css and .js files are valid URLs as I can reach then in my browser and see the code. I also know the dom and the css files are loaded as I added in this function in the script tag:

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
    // When HTML/DOM elements are ready:
    if (event.target.readyState === "interactive") {   //does same as:  ..addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"..
       alert("hi 1");
     
    }
    // When window loaded ( external resources are loaded too- `css`,`src`, etc...) 
    if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
      
          alert("hi 2");
      }
  });
```

Now, from my Android webview code, I call a function in the javascript when the the page is loaded:

```
view?.evaluateJavascript("javascript:setParameters('$mHost','$mToken');",
                        ValueCallback { jsCallback ->
                            Log.v(TAG, jsCallback)
                        })
```

I know the setParameters() function executes as I have an alert in that function. However when I then try to execute a function inside the external .js file I get the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'myObject' of undefined". **NOTE**: I run the function from inside my script tag in the index.html. I know my web developer counter part has had no issues running the same function in the external .js file. Why would I have issues running the external .js inside a webview?

Answer (score 0):

If I was a javascript and not an Android developer I would have figured this out much sooner. I did not receive one answer, this was a lay-up for javascript developers! I hope it saves some other Android dev a ton of time.

The issue was that the script files needed to be added after the DOM elements were ready, because if .js code executes before there are no html elements available.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
        // When HTML/DOM elements are ready:
        if (event.target.readyState === "interactive") {   //does same as:  ..addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"..?
         
          injectScripts()
        }
        //When window loaded ( external resources are loaded too- `css`,`src`, etc...) 
        if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
          alert("scripts ready");
        }
      });
    
    function injectScripts() {
    
        mArrayJs.forEach(element => {
          var s = document.createElement('script');
          s.setAttribute('src', element);
          s.async = false;
          addToBody(s)
        });
      }
    
    function addToBody(js) {
        document.body.appendChild(js);
      }
```